# Swap lines of text around in text file

Tags: python, text-files, swap, lines

I would like to write a pythonV2.7 script that opens a .txt file and reads the input, then reverse 2 specific patterns of lines with out effecting the rest.

The line count is never the same length running as high as 150 thousand lines or more. Below is an example. I would want to swap lines starting with `MO5` with previous `Z` line (this is always constant), and leaving the rest as is. I would then write to new file.txt leaving the original as is.

example.txt:

```
G00 Z 0.1325 
G01 X 2.000 Y 1.00 Z0.00
y 4.000 X 1.00 
Z 0.1325
X 1.000
Y 4.000
X 4.000
M05 (OFF)
G00 Z 0.1325 
G01 X 2.000  X 0.000
Y 4.000 X 1.000
G00 Z 0.1325
M05 (OFF)
```

Comment: your code? we can't help you without you mentioning your tryings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the input and output files in proper file modes. Now iterate over lines and keep previously read line in some variable say `prev` and if a line starts with `M05` then write the current line in the output file, otherwise write the `prev` line.

Here is the code:

```
inp = open('input.txt', 'r')
out = open('output.txt', 'w')
prev = inp.readline()
for line in inp:
   if line.startswith('M05'):
      out.write(line)
      continue
   else:
      out.write(prev)
   prev = line
out.write(prev)
out.close()
inp.close()
```